# Como puedo sumar los valores que me da un contador en python?

Tags: python, contador

Cómo podría sumar los valores que me vaya dando un contador, por ejemplo si primero el resultado me da 1 y luego da 8 como puedo sumar esos dos resultados?

Comment: Hola melissa, bienvenida a [es.so]. Sería bueno que colocaras algo de código, un [mcve] y una explicación más detalla para ver el contexto concreto, sin ello lo más que te puedo decir es que definas la variable con `cont = 0`, y luego actualizas con `cont += resultado` cada vez que lo necesites...

Answer (score 0):

para hacerlo puedes poner dos variables y sumarlas

```
x = 1 # el resultado 1 que dijiste
y = 8 # el otro numero que dijiste

resultado = x+y # aqui se suma x + y
print(resultado) # aqui se pone en pantalla
```

pero si quieres que sea con todos los valores que tu quieras puedes hacer esto

```
 def sumar(*args):
     value = 0
     for i in args: # por cada argumento que diste
         value += i #sumar el argumento a value
     return value
```

y llamas la funcion asi

```
sumar(1,8) #aqui puedes poner todos los valores que tu quieras ejemplo sumar(1,2,3,5)
```